# CakePHP Open to New Tab on Click

Tags: cakephp, hyperlink

I have a function in my application which the users can upload files to the webserver. Then these uploaded files will appear in another page wherein another type of users can click on the link. Once the link is clicked, a new tab will open and the file will be shown.

But I can't seem to do it. Using the 'target' => '_blank' is not working, or I may have put it on the wrong part of the code.

In my case, when you click on the link, the file will load on the same tab.

Here's my code:

```
<?php
    echo $this->Html->link($staff_uploads['StaffUpload']['title'], array(
            'controller' => 'websites', 
            'action' => 'view', 
            'target' => '_blank', 
            $staff_uploads['StaffUpload']['iduploads']
            )
     );
 ?>
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The correct code is:

```
<?php
    echo $this->Html->link($staff_uploads['StaffUpload']['title'], array(
            'controller' => 'websites', 
            'action' => 'view',  
            $staff_uploads['StaffUpload']['iduploads']
            ), array('target' => '_blank')
     );
 ?>
```

And do read the documentation as burzum has suggested.

Answer (score 1):

[Read the documentation.](http://api.cakephp.org/2.6/class-HtmlHelper.html#_link)

HTML attribute options go into the 3rd argument of the link() method, not the second which is the URL as string or array.

Problems like this can be simply resolved by using the documentation.